# couldn't load Images in ImageView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i have an `Activity` with `tabLayout`, i'm trying to create an Image **SlidShow** on the first fragment by Implementing `ViewPagerAdapter`, i am using slidshow with circle indicator, the circle indicator is succesfully displayed, but the images are not.

**this is what i did :**

My Fragment xml layout : **note** that i have a an horizontal `RecyclerView` at the bottom of the `ViewPager` working properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliderLyout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/sliderPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sliderLyout">


            <com.biliki.biliki.bilikiapp.uitemplate.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lastoffersTitle"
                style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_list_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_layout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:rvp_singlePageFling="true"
            app:rvp_triggerOffset="0.1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/restLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_list_recycler">

            <com.biliki.biliki.bilikiapp.uitemplate.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/restTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/restTitle"
                style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/restaurantsRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/restLayout">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is my Adapter Class : i load images using Glide Library.

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int[] mDataList;

    public SliderAdapter(Context mContext, int[] mDataList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mDataList = mDataList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.slider_item_layout, container , false);

        ImageView slideImg = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slide_img);
        int img = mDataList[position];


        GlideApp.
                with(mContext)
                .load(img)
                .centerCrop()
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(slideImg);

        container.addView(rootView, 0);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if(mDataList.length >0){
            return mDataList.length;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
}
```

**The fragment class :**

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createSampleData();

        //...

        sliderPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliderPager);
        sliderPager.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(getContext(),picturesList));
        CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator)rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(sliderPager);

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == picturesList.length) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                sliderPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 2500, 2500);

        return  rootView;
    }
```

and finally this is the result :

[image]

Comment: Are loading image from network? Int Img,  is it drawable I'd?

Comment: img is a drawable id.

Comment: For trouble shoot your issue, could you please set some fixed height and width to the image view say 150dp. And in the instatiateitem method,  since you are loading from your resource folder better avoid glide (for testing ) and use slide image. setImagedrawable  (drawableId)

Comment: i just found the problem, but i couldn't resolve it yet, the problem is that i have a tabLayout with ViewPager in the MainActivity, and i'm t trying to add a ViewPager in one of the Fragments of the tablayout.. i tested my code in an activity and it works fine. 
do you know how to put a ViewPager inside another ?

Comment: i din't resolve the problem, but i found a library in Github that saved my life and it works fine, this one : https://github.com/saeedsh92/Banner-Slider